# React Redux Store Layout: How to handle "pending" state of "add item" request?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

Example store:

```
{
  todos: {
    byId: {
      "1": { id: "1", title: "foo" },
      "2": { id: "2", title: "bar" }
    },
    allIds: ["2", "1"]   // ordered by `title` property
  }
}
```

Now the user wants to add a new Todo Entry:

```
dispatch({
  type: 'ADD_TODO_REQUEST',
  payload: { title: "baz" }
})
```

This triggers some API request: `POST /todos`. The state of the request is `pending` as long as there's **no** response (`success` or `error`). This also means, that I have no `id` yet for the newly created Todo Entry.

Now I already want to add it to the store (and display it). But of course I can't add it to `byId` and `allIds`, because it has no `id` yet.

Question 1: **How should I change the layout of my store to make this possible?**

After the response arrives, there are two possibilities:

1. `success`: Update the store and set the `id` property of the new Todo Entry. Using `dispatch({type:'ADD_TODO_SUCCESS', payload: response.id})`.
2. `error`: Remove the new Todo Entry from the store. Using `dispatch({type:'ADD_TODO_ERROR', payload: ???})`

Now the reducer for those two actions has to somehow find the corresponding element in the store. But it has no identifier.

Question 2: **How do I find the item in the store if it has no `id`?**

---

Additional information:

- I'm using react with redux-saga
- It should be possible to have multiple concurrent `ADD_TODO_REQUEST` running at the same time. Though it must be possible to have multiple `pending` Todo Entries within the store. (For example if the network connection is really slow and the user just enters "title1" and hits the "add" button, then "title2" and "add", "title3" and "add".) Though it's **not** possible to disable the `AddTodo` component while a request is pending.

---

**How do you solve these kind of problems within your applications?**

### EDIT: There's even more:

The same functionality should be available for "updating" and "deleting" Todo Entries:

- When the user edits a Todo Entry and then hits the "save" button, the item should be in the `pending` state, too, until the response arrives. If it's an error, the old version of the data must be put back into the store (without requesting it from the server).
- When the user clicks "delete", then the item will disappear immediately. **But** if the server response is an error, then the item should be put back into the list.

Both actions should restore the previous data, if there's an error respsonse.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to update the state before your API request succeeds and show this unsuccessful (or maybe not) info to the client? Then struggling to fix it. Again, just out of curiosity, I just wonder the use case or advantages here as a learner.

Comment: The Todo Component looks basically like this ( https://codepen.io/codebeast/full/PzVyRm ). Now when you add an item, I want to display it immediately. At this point the new item cannot be clicked / edited / whatever (as long as it's in `pending` state). A Loading Indicator will be displayed for this new item. So the user can see *"I've added this and now I'm waiting for it to save. But while I'm waiting I can add some more items"*. When the request was successful, the new item will flash green and it's done. When there's an error, the new item will flash red and get removed from the list.

Comment: This is really only useful for slow internet connections. The user should see that "something" is happening. With a fast connection it doesn't matter if the new item gets added immediately or if it takes 300 milliseconds. Another useful thing about this is "offline mode": The user can be offline the whole day and see what he already has added to the list. And when the devices comes back online, it will "retry" all the requests and then the data will finally be saved to database.

Comment: @BenjaminM Is it possible in your situation to use uuids? Do you have that kind of control over the codebase?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I see now. A nice option for the client but a lot of work for you :) Maybe you can hold a `tempTodos` in your store and merge those todos with the real ones in the view. If there is success then with another action you can move a todo from the temp. If there is error either you delete them or wait for a retry you mentioned in your comments. By the way, I am so inexperienced with coding, this is just an idea from a noob :)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I could use UUIDs indeed. I posted another answer below using object references. But I'm not sure if that's a good idea. I also mentioned the use of UUIDs (thanks for the idea!). @ devserkan I came up with the same idea (posted as an answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution. **But I'm sure that there are other possibilities and even better solutions.**

Keep the Todo Entries in 2 separate collections:

```
{
  todos: {
    byId: {
      "1": { id: "1", title: "foo" },
      "2": { id: "2", title: "bar" }
    },
    allIds: ["2", "1"],
    pendingItems: [
      { title: "baz" },
      { title: "42" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now I can find them in the store "by reference".

```
// handle 'ADD_TODO_REQUEST':
const newTodoEntry = { title: action.payload.title };
yield put({ type: 'ADD_TODO_PENDING', payload: newTodoEntry });
try {
  const response = yield api.addTodoEntry(newTodoEntry);
  yield put({ type: 'ADD_TODO_SUCCESS', payload: { id: response.id, ref: newTodoEntry } });
} catch(error) {
  yield put({ type: 'ADD_TODO_ERROR', payload: newTodoEntry });
}
```

The reducer will look like this:

```
case 'ADD_TODO_PENDING':
  return {
    ..state,
    pendingItems: // add action.payload to this array
  }

case 'ADD_TODO_SUCCESS':
  const newTodoEntry = { ...action.payload.ref, id: action.payload.id };
  return {
    ..state,
    byId: // add newTodoEntry
    allByIds: // add newTodoEntry.id
    pendingItems: // remove action.payload.ref from this array
  }

case 'ADD_TODO_ERROR':
  return {
    ..state,
    pendingItems: // remove action.payload.ref from this array
  }
```

There are 2 problems:

1. The reducer **must** use the object reference. The reducer is not allowed to create an own object from the action payload of `ADD_TODO_PENDING`.
2. The Todo Entries cannot be sorted easily within the store, because there are two distinct collections.

There are 2 workarounds:

1. Use client side generated `uuid`s which only exist while the items are within the `pending` state. This way, the client can easily keep track of everything.

2.

- a) Add some kind of `insertAtIndex` property to the pending items. Then the React component code can merge those two collections and display the mixed data with a custom order.
- b) Just keep the items separate. For example the list of pending items on top and below that the list of already persisted items from the server database.